# How to lock the size of the item properties panel in QGIS 3 print composer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer

In QGIS 3 (currently running on QGIS 3.28.3 Firenze) the print composer typically contains panels to control aspects of composing (item properties, Atlas, Guides, etc.). . In my case these are arranged at the lower right half of the panels space (red outline in image below). Above there is a panel to control the items and history.

[image: the default appearance of the print composer]

What bugs me is that the lower panel is more important to me. I want it to be broader and to be bigger relative to the upper panels (see image below). Is there a way to control panel sizes and/or set them to my preferences permanently or at least within a project?

[image: my preferred size of the panels on the right in the print composer]

Of course I tried to research this before posting, please excuse if I overlooked something.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle the widgets in the mapcomposer the same way as in the main QGIS window, you can make the item window floating, or remove it completly or dock it anywhere else...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. However, I want the width of e.g. the item properties to remain fixed to my prefences. So far, I have to manually arrange these things each time I open the print composer - which can get annoying really quick.

Comment: yes you are right. May be a feature request would help

Comment: I was hoping there would be another way. Feature requests without proper funding are hardly attractive to the devs as far as I know - but maybe I'll give it a shot